# How to groupby and aggregate multiple fields using combineByKey RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a sample file I am trying to find out for a given field total number of another field and its count and list of values from another field using `combineByKey`. I am trying to understand `combineByKey`, same requirement I understood from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52824098/6695858) using `aggregateByKey`, now I would like to understand `combineByKey`.

I tried the below code which is the same as `aggregateByKey` but I'm getting an type mismatch error. I'm not sure whether my types are correct for `createCombiner` or `mergeValue` or `mergeCombiner`. Please help me to get a good understanding of `combineByKey`.

Sample data:

```
44,8602,37.19
44,8331,99.19
44,1919,39.54
44,2682,41.88
44,7366,66.54
44,3405,81.09
44,9957,94.79
```

Code for `combineByKey`:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///../customer-orders.csv_sample").map(x => x.split(",")).map(x => (x(0).toInt, (x(1).toInt, x(2).toFloat)))

def createCombiner = (tuple: (Seq[Int],Double, Int)) => (tuple,1)

def mergeValue = (acc: (Seq[Int],Double,Int),xs: (Int,Float)) => {
  println(s"""mergeValue: (${acc._1} ++ ${Seq(xs._1)}, ${acc._2} +${xs._2},${acc._3} + 1)""")
  (acc._1 ++ Seq(xs._1), acc._2 + xs._2, acc._3 + 1)
}

def mergeCombiner = (acc1: (Seq[Int],Double,Int), acc2: (Seq[Int],Double,Int)) => {
  println(s"""mergeCombiner: (${acc1._1} ++ ${acc2._1}, ${acc1._2} +${acc2._2}, ${acc1._3} + ${acc2._3})""")
  (acc1._1 ++ acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2, acc1._3 + acc2._3)
}

rdd.combineByKey(createCombiner,mergeValue,mergeCombiner).collect().foreach(println)
```

Error Message:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : ((Seq[Int], Double, Int)) => ((Seq[Int], Double, Int), Int)
required: ((Int, Float)) => ?
rdd.combineByKey(createCombiner,mergeValue,mergeCombiner).collect().foreach(println)
                 ^
```

The expecting result is:

```
customerid, (orderids,..,..,....), totalamount, number of orderids
```

Using the provided sample data it will be:

```
(44,(List(8602, 8331, 1919, 2682, 7366, 3405, 9957),460.2200012207031,7))
```

Mismatch is pointing to `createCombiner`. Could anyone please help to me to understand `combineByKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the `createCombiner` function. Look at `combineByKey`:

```
combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

Simply said, `C` is the format you want to end up with (`(Seq[Int], Double, Int)`) and `V` what you begin with (`(Int, Double)`). Here I changed `Float` to `Double` since that is what is usually used in Spark. That means that the `createCombiner` function should look as follows:

```
def createCombiner = (tuple: (Int, Double)) => (Seq(tuple._1), tuple._2, 1)
```

Both `mergeValue` and `mergeCombiner` looks ok, however, you will not see any print statements in Spark if you execute the code on a cluster (see: [Spark losing println() on stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225994/spark-losing-println-on-stdout)).

Comment: Thanks the `createCombiner` which you provided worked as expected. So the understanding is I need to maintain the type `Double` or `Float` from the map itself and same should be applied to the V that is what i begin and that should be end up with same type.

Comment: @KarthikRamachandran: Exactly, `createCombiner` should take data of the same format as what the RDD contains (the `V` part of the `RDD[(K,V)]` since the key (`K`) is used for grouping). This initial format should then be converted to the most basic combiner so the algorithm can start merging values into it (with `mergeValue`) and combine combiners (with `mergeCombiner`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spark.

I hope this might help you.

```
val array = Array((44,8602,37.19),(44,8331,99.19),(44,1919,39.54),(44,2682,41.88),(44,7366,66.54),(44,3405,81.09),(44,9957,94.79))

array.groupBy(_._1).map(e => (e._1, e._2.map(_._2).toList, e._2.map(_._3).sum))
//res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, List[Int], Double)] = List((44,List(8602, 8331, 1919, 2682, 7366, 3405, 9957),460.21999999999997))
```

I see your this error is due to

> def createCombiner = (tuple: (Seq[Int],Double, Int)) => (tuple,1)

I think `createCombiner` should take some `Seq` of tuples and return a tuples of `Int` and `Seq` (groupby)

> def createCombiner = (tuple: Seq[(Int,Int, Double)]) => tuple.groupBy(_._1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the signature of combineByKey:

```
combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

mergeValue is of type `(C, V) => C`

Where C should be `((Seq[Int],Double, Int), Int)` and V should be `(Seq[Int],Double, Int)`

Your mergeValue method has types C `(Seq[Int],Double,Int)` and V `(Int,Float)`

The type of mergeCombiner is also incorrect.

This should be `(C, C) => C` where C is `((Seq[Int],Double, Int), Int)`